# Jacob, Can't co-create object

Tags: windows, java-8, jacob

**My setup:**
I'm trying to create a web-API that converts a docx file to pdf using the Java-COM-Bridge known as Jacob.

**Current state:**
I have it working on my local machine (Windows 10), when I run the project from IDE.
I also have the project working on a local VM (Windows Server 2019), from a compiled war file.
I can't get the project working on a AWS-VM (Windows Server 2019), from the compiled war file.

**My issue:**
When I try to create the `ActiveXComponent` in java, it fails with `com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't co-create object`.

**Other details:**
I have .NET 3.5 and older installed, and vcredis 2005.
All the machines run 64 bit (java, tomcat, office, etc.)
I tried running `New-Object -ComObject Word.Application` in PS and it returns info about word, so it is registered.
I can also find Word, in *OLE View*.
I'm running jacob 1.20 (latest version)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a DCOM event ID 10016 in my Event Log.
So basically it is a permission issue...

**EDIT**
Actually the issue was, that my network was declared as *public*, thus making the firewall block a lot of stuff, also DCOM/COM+ communication.
So all I would have to do was change the network from *public* to *private*...
Or so I though, because that didn't fix anything, it's still not working on AWS.